# we don't want to display any query params on our login authentication page. how can we acheive it using kinde

Tags: authentication, oauth

[image: extra query params on auth page]

[image: custom domain registered with kinde]

we are using kinde auth for authentication.upon clicking the login link it redirects to this page and after authentication it redirects back to our specified path. we want this auth url to look simple. is there anyway to acheive it ?. we have tried kinde docs and other customization option but have not found anything useful. we have tried registering our custom domain with kinde as well.

Comment: Hi, Daniel here from Kinde.

Can I start by asking which SDK you're using?  Will help me advise best.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a completely clean URL what you could do is use a custom sign up / sign in page. This essentially allows you to host the Google and LinkedIn buttons in your app.

1. Go into Kinde admin and turn on the `Use your own sign-up and sign-in screens` option in the Authentication experience section.
2. Get the connection ID of the social login you wish to use from the Social connections section.
3. Pass in the Kinde `connection_id` you grabbed in step 2 to the auth url params of the method you wish to use.

This example is in React but the same principle works regardless of technology:

```
    <button
        onClick={() =>
            login({
                authUrlParams: {
                    connection_id: "conn_6a95dec504d34dc286dc80e8df9f6099"
                }
            })
        }
    >
        Sign in with Google
    </button>
```

For full details the doc can be found here: https://kinde.com/docs/authentication-and-access/custom-authentication-pages/